# There is no python-dotenv library installed by Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dotenv

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install python-dotenv
RUN pip install other_libraries...
```

During building container, message is displayed:

```
...
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install python-dotenv
---> Running in 5fffd3fe4042
Collecting python-dotenv
Downloading python_dotenv-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.15.0
Removing intermediate container 5fffd3fe4042
---> 2cd0942f520c
...
```

But when I run `docker-compose exec container_name pip list` there is no on list `python-dotenv` library.

I tried on `python:3.9`, `python:3.8` with `python-dotenv` in 0.14 or 0.15 version.

Of course, when I run `docker-compose exec container_name pip install python-dotenv` everything is okey.

Why `RUN` command in Dockerfile not installed correctly?

Comment: as I know, Dockerfile using for build images, not containers. After build image you need to run container using built image. Why you using docker-compose? Do you have some yaml configuration?

Comment: I just built your image and ran it, and `pip list` shows me 4 packages, one being `python-dotenv 0.15.0`.  If I launch into Python, doing `from dotenv import load_dotenv; load_dotenv()` works and prints `True`. - I don't use docker-compose, so I don't know how to help you if you aren't even running or seeing into the container properly. - in short...I think your Dockerfile is fine.

Comment: Okay, my docker-compose used old service.

Comment: It would help if you also showed the docker-compose YAML file. Maybe the container you are starting using docker-compose is not from the same image you are building with python-dotenv. As others have mentioned, your Dockerfile RUN command should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step.

1. Build image that including python libraries (using your Dockerfile)

```sh
docker build -t dotenv_image:1.0 .
```

2. List images

```sh
docker images
```

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dotenv_image              1.0                 507f2d0505a0        4 minutes ago       891MB
```

↑Okay it is here

3. Run container with `sh` shell to be able run commands and check what inside container

```sh
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh dotenv_image:1.0
```

4. Check libraries

```sh
pip freeze
```

```sh
python-dotenv==0.15.0
```

Library is here

5. Try to use library

```sh
python -c 'from dotenv import load_dotenv; print("ALL OK" if load_dotenv() else "CAN NOT LOAD")';
```

```
ALL OK
```

↑Positive output

Comment: Didn't see this answer until I posted mine.  I'll delete mine.  One thing you could do is something I did...also show that if you launch into Python, you can run `from dotenv import load_dotenv; load_dotenv()` at the Python prompt and get the expected `True` as an output.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for check. Added output for load_dotenv. Your answer also correct. No reason to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use docker-compose, but since your title says that your Dockerfile isn't working right, I can tell you that that's apparently not the problem.  Your Dockerfile seems to work just fine:

```
>>> cat Dockerfile
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install python-dotenv

>>> docker build -t so2 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM python:3.9
3.9: Pulling from library/python
e4c3d3e4f7b0: Pull complete
101c41d0463b: Pull complete
8275efcd805f: Pull complete
751620502a7a: Pull complete
0a5e725150a2: Pull complete
397dba5694db: Pull complete
b1d09d0eabcb: Pull complete
475299e7c7f3: Pull complete
d2fe14d8e6bc: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:429b2fd1f6657e4176d81815dc9e66477d74f8cbf986883c024c9b97f7d4d5a6
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.9
 ---> 5336a27a9b1f
Step 2/3 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 37b03142a9b6
Removing intermediate container 37b03142a9b6
 ---> 4677ab34ce84
Step 3/3 : RUN pip install python-dotenv
 ---> Running in e89d17be1a32
Collecting python-dotenv
  Downloading python_dotenv-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
Successfully installed python-dotenv-0.15.0
Removing intermediate container e89d17be1a32
 ---> 55d00eeae4b4
Successfully built 55d00eeae4b4
Successfully tagged so2:latest

>>> docker run -it so2 bash
root@d211989c4bd7:/usr/src/app# pip list
Package       Version
------------- -------
pip           20.2.4
python-dotenv 0.15.0
setuptools    50.3.2
wheel         0.35.1
root@d211989c4bd7:/usr/src/app# exit

>>> docker run -it so2
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 13 2020, 20:14:06)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from dotenv import load_dotenv; load_dotenv()
True
>>>
```

`>>>` represent my prompt in my MacBook pro Terminal window.